# CakePHP 3.0 Modelless Pagination

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have data coming from an API that I want to show results for using CakePHP's pagination. Everything I see for the pagination requires a query or model object to be passed in. Is it possible to pass in something like an array of the data or total items, current item, and items per page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was easier than I anticipated. I was able to add a paging element to the request params. The pagination component doesn't need to be touched at all.

```
$data = $Utility->getData();
$perPage = 20;
$count = count($data);
$page = isset($this->request->query['page']) ? $this->request->query['page'] : 1;
$offset = $perPage * ($page - 1);
$pageCount = floor($count / $perPage);
$this->request->params['paging'] = [
    'Messages' => [
        'page' => $page,
        'current' => $offset,
        'count' => $count,
        'perPage' => $perPage,
        'prevPage' => $page != 1,
        'nextPage' => $page != $pageCount,
        'pageCount' => $pageCount,
    ]
];
```

Comment: More possible keys can be found in **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.12/src/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php#L193**

Comment: I think you should use ceil() instead of floor() when calculating $pageCount